# Need grammatical help on a German phrase (romantic literature) involving "ward" (old form of "wurde")?

Tags: grammar, literature, poetry

While reading Heinrich von Kleist´s *Die Marquise von O* (very easy to read thanks to Kleist´s  extensive usage of commas...), I stumbled upon a phrase which I couldn´t quite explain, even if the meaning is pretty clear.

> Bald darauf ward der Familie, eben zu einer Zeit, da sich auch der Forstmeister von G..., des Kommandanten Sohn, in dem Hause eingefunden hatte, der sonderbare Schrecken, durch einen Kammerdiener, der ins Zimmer trat, den Grafen F... anmelden zu hören.

or :

> Bald darauf ward der Familie der sonderbare Schrecken, durch einen Kammerdiener den Grafen F... anmelden zu hören.

(Spoiler: F... is thought to be dead and buried at that time of the novel)

The way I understand it, either it is a typing mistake or a old form for (die Familie ? Somehow "der Familie" klingt besser) or I can´t find the subject (special grammatical form?).

Answer (score 7):

"ward" is an old form of "wurde". This construction

> Der Familie ward der sonderbare Schrecken, den Grafen F. anmelden zu hören.

means

> Die Familie hatte den sonderbaren Schrecken, den Grafen F. anmelden zu hören.

In modern German you wouldn't say "Mir wurde es Schrecken". To most people this will sound grammatically wrong. However some similar expressions survived and are still used, like "Mir wurde es Angst und Bange", which used to be "Mir ward es Angst und Bange". Coming back to your example this would look like

> Der Familie wurde es Angst und Bange...

Comment: Thanks, so it can be seen like the fear "came to the family" ("der Schrecken wurde der Familie") ? Or is an "es" implied (but then "der Schrecken" cannot be the subject anymore)?

Comment: "Schrecken" is in this case not the grammatical subject. The grammatical subject is in all those cases "es" and in the original example the sentence is called "subjektlos", because the subject would be "es" in a sentence "Der Familie ward es Schrecken...". This "es" is in many cases negligible. "Es wird mir übel" -> "Mir wird übel" etc.

Comment: Thanks, so why the nominative case (der besondere Schrecken) ?

Comment: @Axel Das ist leider falsch. **Subjekt ist hier "Schrecken"!** "Werden" ist hier absolutes Verb in der Bedeutung "widerfahren". Siehe Grimms Wörterbuch, sv. *werden*, I.C.1. Beispiel von Schiller: "dem mann musz hülfe werden". http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW17452 Hier fehlt also kein "es"! "Der Familie wurde Schrecken, ... zu hören." bedeutet: "Der Familie widerfuhr der Schrecken, ... zu hören."

Comment: Oh, das wusste ich wirklich nicht. Ich dachte immer es wurde ein "es" weggelassen, weil sich alle entsprechenden Sätze um dieses "es" erweitern lassen. Man lernt nie aus. Danke!

Answer (score 1):

It is already mentioned in the other answers, that "ward" is an old form of "wurde". So a  translation I consider as quite similar in English would be: "Soon afterwards the family was [this is the ward-counterpiece] subjected to the peculiar horror, to get count F. announced by the servant."

A little bit more modern would have been "ward ... zuteil", "zuteil" being the correspondence to the "subjected" above.

Comment: As I said, I perfectly understood the meaning, but your translation doesn´t grammatically stick to the original. In German it would be something like : "Der Familie wurde (es) den besonderen Schrecken (angetan)" (a passive impersonal form), or "Die Familie unterlag dem besonderen Schrecken..." (or some passive form with "Die Familie" as subject), i.e. Schrecken would be a complement (bad translations, but I only wish to underline that I don´t understand how "der Schrecken" can be the subject of the phrase).